# Matplotlib - MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, matplotlib, deprecation-warning

I have made a program, that makes a random walk and plots it. And it works perfectly, but I get a warning every time I run the program. It says:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  
In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed,
and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
```

The warning warns me about, when I try to remove the x and y axis in `rw_visual.py`

My `random_walk.py` (If you need to test it):

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk():
    """A class to generate random walks."""

    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        """Initialize attributes of a walk."""
        self.num_points = num_points

        # All walks start at (0, 0).
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        """Calculate all the points in the walk."""

        # Keep taking steps until the walk reaches the desired length.
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:

            # Decide which direction to go and how far to go in that direction.
            x_direction = choice([1, -1])
            x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance

            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            # Reject moves that go nowhere.
            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue

            # Calculate the next x and y values.
            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)
```

My `rw_visual.py` (Where the warning occurs):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random_walk import RandomWalk

# Keep making new walks, as long as the program is active.
while True:
    # Make random walk, and plot the points.
    rw = RandomWalk()
    rw.fill_walk()

    point_numbers = list(range(rw.num_points))
    plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, c=point_numbers, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                edgecolor='none', s=10)

    # Emphasize the first and last points.
    plt.scatter(0, 0, c='green', edgecolors='none', s=150)
    plt.scatter(rw.x_values[-1], rw.y_values[-1], c='red', edgecolors='none',
                s=150)

    # Remove the axes.
    plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False) # This is what it warns me about, I think.
    plt.axes().get_yaxis().set_visible(False) # It also warns me about this.
    plt.show()

    keep_running = input("Make another walk? (y/n): ")
    if keep_running == 'n':
        break
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`plt.axes()` activates the already created axes (which was created when you did `plt.scatter`). The warning is telling you that in future releases, rather than activating the already created axes, it will create a *new* axes instance.

What you probably want is to get the axes that is currently being using. You can do this easily using `plt.gca()`.

So replace

```
plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False) 
plt.axes().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

with

```
plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```